# MySQL: If a selected field in stored procedure has NULL value I want to return N/A as value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm using `phpmyadmin` and I have the following stored procedure:

```
SELECT im.onset_date,
im.end_date,
im.coding_id,
im.patient_id,
im.resolution_circumstances, 
FROM illness_mapping as im
WHERE im.patient_id = p_id and im.end_date <= CURDATE()
```

`p_id` value is insert by the user.

In some records `im.resolution_circumstances` is null. When I call the stored procedure I want to find if it's null and return the value `N/A`. I only want to return the value and not to store it to the specific field in the database.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You want to use `COALESCE`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Do you have an example of how to use it and incorporate it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` to check whether your property is null or not

```
 SELECT im.onset_date,
    im.end_date,
    im.coding_id,
    im.patient_id,
(case 
    when im.resolution_circumstances is null 
       then "N/A"
    when im.resolution_circumstances is not null 
       then im.resolution_circumstances
  end) as resolution_circumstances
    FROM illness_mapping as im
    WHERE im.patient_id = p_id and im.end_date <= CURDATE()
```